# Validating a text field using onchange event?

Tags: html, onchange

I have a JSP page with a form in it.

The form has many fields including text fields, radio buttons etc.

I have a special field called as emp id. This is a text field.

This emp id has to be of 9 characters long. If it is less than or greater than 9 chars then I need to give alert message to the user that the emp id entered is invalid.

I have written a javascript method to validate this field which is fired on the **onchange** event of this field.

Now, I have made this field as the auto lookup. So, user can enter first few digits and then can see the list of existing emp ids populated in the emp id field.

This is pretty much how the auto lokups work generally.

The problem is when user tries to select the emp id from auto lookup, since the mouse pointer moves out of text field, the onchange event is fired.

This is wrong, I want the event to be fired after the value is selected from the auto lookup list or when the value is entered manually.

Please help.

I am using jquery auto lookup.

Below is my JSP code.

```
    <script>
    $(function() {

        function validateEmpId(empId) {
            empId = $.trim(empId);
            empId = empId.replace(/\s/g, "");
            if (empId.length != 9) {
                alert("Please enter a valid Emp Id.");
            }
        }

        $("#empId")
                .autocomplete(
                        {
                            source : function(request, response) {

                                $.ajax({
                                    url : "${findEmployeesByEmpIdIdUrl}"
                                            + "?t=" + getTimestamp()
                                            + "&hcAsOnDate=" + hcAsOnDate,
                                    datatype : "json",
                                    data : {
                                        dbPrismId : request.term
                                    },
                                    success : function(data) {
                                        response($.map(data, function(item) {
                                            return {
                                                label : item.dbPrismId,
                                                value : item.dbPrismId,
                                                id : item.id + "_"
                                                        + item.forecast
                                            };
                                        }));
                                    }
                                });
                            },
                            minLength : 1,
                            select : function(event, ui) {
                                var employeeId = ui.item.id;


                            },
                            open : function() {
                                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass(
                                        "ui-corner-top");
                            },
                            close : function() {
                                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass(
                                        "ui-corner-all");
                            }
                        });

    });
</script>

<form action="save" method="POST" name="employeeForm" id="employeeForm">
    <input type="text" name="empId" id="empId" maxlength="9" onchange="validateEmpId(this.value);" class="input-txt" />
</form>
```

Comment: What's your code for the auto lookup?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this inside your select function:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    if (validateEmpId(ui.item.id)) self.location.href='?site=whatever&id=' + ui.item.id;
    else alert("Please enter a valid Emp Id.");  
}


function validateEmpId(empId) { 
    empId = $.trim(empId); 
    empId = empId.replace(/\s/g, ""); 
    if (empId.length != 9) return false;
    else return true;
}
```

Comment: select function is being called after the validation alert is shown.

Comment: Than validate when the select is done and when it's correct do the location.href else an error alert. (Edited my post with example)

Comment: ShogunArts.de The emp id can also be entered manually. How do I validate such emp id. In order to do this I have called the validate method on the onchange event of text field.

Comment: No, on the onsubmit event :) When you use the autocomplete, there will be no event. Even when you select is NO submit event. So you need to check when you select the ID, but when you enter manually you need to check on submit.

Comment: I need to give the validation alert to the user as soon as he enters the emp id. I cant wait till the user fills up the entire form and then submit the form. Emp id is the most important field in the form and if its invalid, I need to let them know ASAP. Hence the onchange event. But unfortunately Auto lookup seems to have problems with the onchange. Is there any other way around?